# Hover + click on image button

Tags: jquery

I try to write a jQuery code to manage my images buttons.

I would like to create buttons with this behaviours : **http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/fhL7w/17/**

But the difference is that they are images buttons. I have several. So I would like to manage with their file names "-normal", "-hover".

My images buttons don't behave as I would : **http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/z562Y/** how can I fix it ?

I wrote this :

```
<img id="btn-clients" class="btn toggleImg rollover" src="http://pepitodanger.free.fr/forms/images/clients-normal.png" alt="">

function toggleImg() {
    var file = $(this).attr('src');
    var src = (file.indexOf('-hover') == -1) ? file.replace("-normal", "-hover") : file.replace("-hover", "-normal");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
}

$('.toggleImg').hammer().on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', toggleImg);



$('img.rollover').on('mouseenter', function () {
    this.src = this.src.replace("-normal", "-hover");
});

$('img.rollover').on('mouseleave', function () {
    this.src = this.src.replace("-hover", "-normal");
});
```

Comment: This can be, and probably should be, done with `CSS`.

Comment: could you explain in detail what your looking for?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6az8T/1/

Comment: @DaveZych Ok but if I have several images buttons ? I have to manage the "background: url()" for everyone ? :-/

Comment: Please include a question, or description of the problem you are having.  Thanks!

Comment: @niko, I have several images buttons. 
I would like them to behave as : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/fhL7w/17/

I know that I can do this in CSS, but I don't want to manage "background: url()" in CSS for each buttons, I have many. I tried to manage their behavior in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toggleImg(e) {
    if (e.type == 'click') {
        $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
    }else if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        this.src = this.src.indexOf('-hover') == -1 ? this.src.replace("-normal", "-hover") : this.src.replace("-hover", "-normal");
    }
}

$('.toggleImg').hammer().on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', toggleImg);
$('img.rollover').on('mouseenter mouseleave', toggleImg);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z562Y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the example code is doing two things:

1. Changing a color
2. Changing a class

Whereas your code does only one thing:

1. Changing a `src` image

So both events in your code (hover, click) do the same thing, and subsequently undo the same thing.  In order to achieve the result of the example, you should break the events into two things:

1. Changing a background
2. Changing a class

Take a look at a modified version of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z562Y/1/).  What I've done is simplified the markup a little and turned the `img` into a `div` (to be styled with a background):

```
<div id="btn-clients" class="btn inactive" />
```

Then I styled it with the hover change, as well as created some additional classes for the click events:

```
html, body {
    background: #d2d4d5;
}
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 26px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(http://pepitodanger.free.fr/forms/images/clients-normal.png);
}

.btn:hover {
    background: url(http://pepitodanger.free.fr/forms/images/clients-hover.png);
}

.active {
    background: url(http://pepitodanger.free.fr/forms/images/clients-hover.png);
}

.inactive {
    background: url(http://pepitodanger.free.fr/forms/images/clients-normal.png);
}
```

Finally, the JavaScript is simplified to match the original example for simply toggling the classes:

```
$('.btn').on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive active');
});
```

This much more closely matches the implementation of the example, and thus mimics the functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I know :( but I have several buttons to manage. I must write each background: url() for each images buttons ? Guess I have more than 10 to manage ?

Comment: @Xroad: If they're different then yes.  Of course, if they're different then you already need to manage several `src` attributes.  You may be able to make it more generic in JavaScript, directly modifying the style properties instead of using existing CSS classes.  However, while the result may be fewer lines of code, it would likely also be more complex and more fragile and, thus, more difficult to support.